# How to parse php input array into json then back to php

Tags: php, json, ajax

So I am making a checkbox for each row in my table so I can delete multiple rows at once.

I am trying to do this for each row inside my table:

```
<td><input id="checkItem" name="delete[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$product->id;?>"></td>
```

Then delete[] is holding the array.

My issue is, I am using json (ajax) to parse my data.

It is only recognizing the last delete[] checkbox I have on my page.
If I check the last checkbox and hit delete all (my button to execute multi-selected rows), it shows the product id, this is good.

If I try any other checkbox, it returns nothing.

Here is the checkbox line that creates checkbox array for each row:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w4b7.png)

Here is the post function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lISf.png)

Here is my delete function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fqIR.png)

Here is my json ajax code to process the requests:

```
$("body").on("submit", ".ajax-form", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    form = $(this);

    url = form.attr("action");
    method = form.attr("method");
    data = {};

    form.find("[name]").each(function (key, value) {
        type = $(this).attr("type");
        name = $(this).attr("name");

        if (type == "radio" || type == "checkbox") {
            value = "";

            if ($(this).prop("checked")) value = $(this).val();
        } else value = $(this).val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    button_lang = $("[type=submit]", form).html();


    var saveData = $.ajax({
          type: method,
          crossDomain: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
          url: url,
          data: data,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
            messages = "";
            if(response.success === true)
            {
                if(response.redirect)
                {
                  $('.ajax-form').trigger("reset");
                  window.location.href = response.redirect;
                }
                else if(response.success)
                {
                    for (var message in response.messages) {
                        messages += response.messages[message] + "<br>";
                    }
                    if(response.timer) {
                        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                          toast: true,
                          position: 'top-end',
                          showConfirmButton: false,
                          timer: 3000,
                          timerProgressBar: true,
                          onOpen: (toast) => {
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                          }
                        });

                        Toast.fire({
                          icon: 'success',
                          title: "<h6 style='text-align: left!important;'>" + messages + "</h6>"
                        });
                        $('.ajax-form').trigger("reset");
                        window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = response.sendTo;},response.timer);
                    } else {

                        const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                          toast: true,
                          position: 'top-end',
                          showConfirmButton: false,
                          timer: 3000,
                          timerProgressBar: true,
                          onOpen: (toast) => {
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                            toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                          }
                        });

                        Toast.fire({
                          icon: 'success',
                          title: "<h6 style='text-align: left!important;'>" + messages + "</h6>"
                        });

                        $('.ajax-form').trigger("reset");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (var message in response.messages) {
                    messages += response.messages[message] + "<br>";
                }
                const Toast = Swal.mixin({
                  toast: true,
                  position: 'top-end',
                  showConfirmButton: false,
                  timer: 3000,
                  timerProgressBar: true,
                  onOpen: (toast) => {
                    toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
                    toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
                  }
                });

                Toast.fire({
                  icon: 'error',
                  title: "<h6 style='text-align: left!important;'>" + messages + "</h6>"
                });
            }
          }
    });

    saveData.fail(function() {
      const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        onOpen: (toast) => {
          toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
          toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
        }
      });

      Toast.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: "<h6 style='text-align: left!important;'>A system error occured</h6>"
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: You should try to narrow down your problem. It's most likely in the step where you gather input values. I'd do `console.log(data)` to see what it holds after you iterate the inputs. Also, any reason why you don't just [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But @El_Vanja is right. Your code is highly room for improvement

```
 form.find('input:checkbox').each(function (key, value) {

        type = $(this).attr("type");
        name = $(this).attr("name");

        if (type == "radio" || type == "checkbox") {
            value = "";

            if ($(this).prop("checked")) value = $(this).val();
        } else value = $(this).val();

        data.push({name:value});

    });
```